# Можно ли сказать "педали набирали обороты"

Tags: грамматика

Речь идет о велотренажере. Можно ли в этом случае сказать "педали велотренажера стремительно набирали обороты"?

Comment: Спасибо! :) Вы мне очень помогли!

Answer (score 1):

Фраза формально правильна, но при этом искусственна и чужеродна повседневному языку. Попробую объяснить почему.

С развитием машиностроения, словосочетание "набирать обороты" родилось как аналог "набирать ход".  Последняя фраза появилась у железнодорожников и капитанов паровых судов для обозначения разгона тяжёлой махины (паровоза, парохода).  Не принято говорить, что птичка или рыбка набирает ход.

По аналогии, "набирать обороты" может что-то массивное и инертное, что непросто разогнать -- но и остановить непросто. Скажем, можно сказать "турбина набирала обороты", "двигатель набирал обороты". А о колесе ветряной мельницы я бы так уже не сказал; о велосипедных педалях и подавно.

Comment: Мне кажется, ваше обоснование довольно надумано. Фраза _"набирал обороты"_ используется в самых разных контекстах, и ассоциации с чем-то массивным у неё не наблюдается. Достаточно полистать [гугл](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=1514&bih=974&ei=vJYwXdnQPPXImwWj0qbIBA&q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B%22&oq=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...0.0..22197...0.0..0.0.0.......0......gws-wiz.POAqxR5IwWA&ved=0ahUKEwjZntXA6r7jAhV15KYKHSOpCUk4KBDh1QMICg&uact=5).

Comment: @freim  Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что я говорю лишь о буквальном, не переносном, употреблении этого словосочетания. И, будучи по первому образованию инженером, я в ответе вполне уверен.

Comment: Я вообще-то тоже инженер, так что это не аргумент. Ваше обоснование выглядит очень натянутым. Да, так говорят о большой турбине, но точно так же можно сказать (и говорят) "набирает обороты" о крохотном моторчике для детской игрушки. Естественно, про инертные вещи так говорят чаще, но вы из этого делаете вывод, что так говорят только о массивных и инертных вещах. Логическая ошибка.

Comment: @freim  Возможно, Вы правы. Не стану упорствовать. Хотя мне трудно представить, чтобы кто-то сказал об игрушечном электромоторчике, что он "набирает обороты". А о роторе турбины так говорят.

Comment: _" Хотя мне трудно представить, чтобы кто-то сказал об игрушечном электромоторчике..."_ - легко! Например, фраза _"игрушечный мотор моментально набирает обороты"_ выглядит совершенно естественно. Понимаете, вы изначально представили себе огромную турбину, и отсюда по ассоциации пошла неправильная цепочка, что эта фраза относится к чему-то большому, что обороты набираются медленно, и т.д. А на самом деле фраза-то совершенно нейтральная и применима к чему угодно.

Answer (score 0):

Сказать, пожалуй, можно, но выглядит это не совсем русским языком. Как будто иностранец писал. Напишите *"педали вращались всё быстрее"*, так точно не режет глаз.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/29186)

Comment: @behemothus, не вполне уловил, почему вы не считаете это ответом. Вы не могли бы уточнить свою претензию?

Comment: Это текст из списка "очереди проверок", куда попадают сообщения, не прошедшие формальный контроль. Один из возможных кормментариев, но список короткий, на все случаи не подберешь. "ответ"  недостаточно иформативет, не содер

Comment: Конкретно у вас ответ полностью субъективен, страдает полным отсутствием логически обоснованной позиции и хотябы ссылок на таковую. Такое рекомендуется писать разве что в комментариях -  да и то без особой нужды лучше не надо,

Comment: @behemothus, хотел бы я посмотреть на полностью объективный ответ о применимости выражения _"стремительно набирали обороты"_ именно к педалям. Полагаете, что-то на эту тему можно найти в словарях? В общем случае ваша претензия была бы обоснована, но я сомневаюсь, что именно на данный вопрос можно ответить иначе, чем с точки зрения носителя языка.

Comment: Можете обсудить на Мете.

Comment: @behemothus, что обсудить? Необходимость удаления? Так вы уже проголосовали, что тут ещё обсуждать. Применимость выражения? Так у меня только субъективные ощущения, и у вас, я уверен, тоже. Нет темы для обсуждения совершенно, ни там, ни тут.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96312/discussion-between-behemothus-and-freim).